# How to use sqlite3 in C without the dev library installed?

Tags: sql, c, bash, sqlite

I'm trying to load a local DB with SQLite under a RedHat Linux server. I have a C code to load the database from a very large file spliting the columns. The bad new is that sqlite3 is not installed in the machine (`fatal error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory`) and I won't be able to have permissions to install `libsqlite3-dev` ([acording to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31764947/1709738)) , so I could only use it throuth bash or python:

```
[dhernandez@zl1:~]$ locate sqlite3
/opt/xiv/host_attach/xpyv/lib/libsqlite3.so
/opt/xiv/host_attach/xpyv/lib/libsqlite3.so.0
/opt/xiv/host_attach/xpyv/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
/opt/xiv/host_attach/xpyv/lib/python2.7/sqlite3
/opt/xiv/host_attach/xpyv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so
/opt/xiv/host_attach/xpyv/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py
/opt/xiv/host_attach/xpyv/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py
/opt/xiv/host_attach/xpyv/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dump.py
/usr/bin/sqlite3
/usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0
/usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
/usr/lib64/python2.6/sqlite3
/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so
/usr/lib64/python2.6/sqlite3/__init__.py
/usr/lib64/python2.6/sqlite3/__init__.pyc
/usr/lib64/python2.6/sqlite3/__init__.pyo
/usr/lib64/python2.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.py
/usr/lib64/python2.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.pyc
/usr/lib64/python2.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.pyo
/usr/lib64/python2.6/sqlite3/dump.py
/usr/lib64/python2.6/sqlite3/dump.pyc
/usr/lib64/python2.6/sqlite3/dump.pyo
/usr/lib64/xulrunner/libmozsqlite3.so
/usr/share/man/man1/sqlite3.1.gz
/usr/share/mime/application/x-kexiproject-sqlite3.xml
/usr/share/mime/application/x-sqlite3.xml
```

What would be faster of the following options?

1. Split the columns in my C program, and then execute the insert like
   this:

   ```
   system("echo 'insert into t values(1,2);'" | sqlite3 mydb.db);
   ```
2. Split the columns in my C program, save it to a temp file and when
   I've got 500.000 rows I execute the script like this (and then empty
   the temp file to continue loading rows):

   ```
   system("sqlite3 mydb.db < temp.sql);
   ```
3. Split the columns in my C program adding a delimiter between them, save it to a temp file and import it like this:

   ```
   .delimiter '@'
   .import temp.txt t
   ```

Comment: I don't get it. You don't have sqlite3 installed, yet you ask which command with sqlite3 you would need to call... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [amalgation](https://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html) version. It is a single `.c` file you can include in your project, and all of SQLite is available. No need for dynamic linking.

Comment: I've downloaded the file `C source code as an amalgamation, version 3.11.1.` of the download page, I've uploaded it to my home, and then I've put on the top `#include "/home/llami/sqlite3.c"` but it returns a lot of compilation errors: https://gist.github.com/mllamazing/18c33c2ff55b25c94293 Am I dismissing something?

Comment: "Include in your project" is not the same as "include in some .c file". Just compile it like any of your other .c files.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Finally I solve it using these steps: http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg30132.html Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try to dynamically load the sqlite3 library at runtime.
There are quite few stuff to learn about it, but that's a powerful functionality and I am quite sure this would solve your problem.

Here is a link describing how you can do it : http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/dl-libraries.html

Answer (score 0):

Download the devel package and use it from your project directory. You only need it for the compilation.